Where is "Reopen in Container" in VS code?
I' m going to reopen docker file in vs code.
However I could not find "Reopen in Container" in spite of that I have already installed "Dev Containers".
What should I do?
I put "reopen" in the search window but could not find it.

Search on command palette (press F1/⇧⌘P/Ctrl+Shift+P depending on your OS)

what search window?

thank you for your reply. I have already checked on command palette and search window, but I couldn't.
